# Проблема с упаковкой в exe файл консольного приложения .net core 6.0. Остаются библиотеки от Emgu.CV.runtime.windows в отдельных файлых

Tags: c#

Я пишу консольное приложение для получения видео с веб камеры. Но я не могу скомпилировать всё в один .exe файл, проблема вроде в подключенной библиотеке Emgu.CV.runtime.windows, так как без неё вроде всё нормально упаковывается с помощью публикации в локальную папку с созданием отдельного файла, но без неё и приложение не работает.
В интернете ничего не нашел, везде говорится как раз про публикацию.

Comment: Вероятно, это нативные библиотеки. Следовательно, они не могут быть слиты в один управляемый exe-файл.

Comment: А можно ли тогда как-то собрать всё в один исполняемый файл?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov читать самый конец ответа по ссылке из дубликата. :) `<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>`